# Constraint violated?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

having some trouble figuring out what's causing the error.  I've included the code, the error and what I see when I look at the table constraint tab.  I've been searching online and trying suggestions however nothing has worked.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so hopefully someone can help give me a little push or point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

[image]

```
        STSQL = "insert into mpcs.shop_inv_orders"
        STSQL = STSQL & " ("
        STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER_ID,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER_ITEM_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "INV_TYPE,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "MTI_PART_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "DATE_ORDERED,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "DATE_REQUIRED,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "QUANTITY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "EMPLOYEE_ID,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "MACHINE_ID,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "COMMENTS,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "JOB_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "PROCESS_PLAN_ID,"
        'STSQL = STSQL & "ACCOUNT_NO"
        STSQL = STSQL & "DESTINATION,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "COMPLETED,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "REQUEST_NO"
        STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("

        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(varOrderID) & "'," 'ORDER_ID
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Item) & "'," 'ORDER_ITEM_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(InvType) & "'," 'INV_TYPE
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Mtipartno) & "'," 'MTI_PART_NO

        STSQL = STSQL & "to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')," 'DATE_ORDERED
        STSQL = STSQL & "to_date('" & Format(dateneed.Value, "dd-MMMM-yyyy") & "','DD-MON-YYYY')," 'DATE_REQUIRED

        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Quantity) & "'," 'QUANTITY
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(cboEmployee.SelectedValue) & "'," 'EMPLOYEE_ID
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(MachID) & "'," 'MACHINE_ID
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(TextBox2.Text) & "'," 'COMMENTS
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Jobno) & "'," 'JOB_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ProcPlanID) & "'," 'PROCESS_PLAN_ID
        'STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(AcctNo) & "'," 'ACCOUNT_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ComboBox2.SelectedText) & "'," 'DESTINATION
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & 0 & "'," 'COMPLETED
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ReqNo) & "'" 'REQUEST_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & ")"
```

[image]

Comment: You're trying to insert an ORDER_ID that already exists in you table.

Comment: I looked and it doesn't.  I used the next available.

Comment: No, you're definitely trying to insert the same (ORDER_ID + ORDER_ITEM_NO combo). That might mean your algorithm for getting the next number is broken, or that you're running in a concurrent scenario where multiple users are adding orders at the same time, or that you're in a transaction isolation level that hides in-progress orders from your query, or that someone added an order id out of order, or... Look at your data. Look at the key you're trying to insert. Have a revelation.

Comment: The table is not be using, its not in production right now.  I sorted the column and manually tried the next one this time.  Same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this,Order_Id is primary key so can't add manually,

```vb
STSQL = "insert into mpcs.shop_inv_orders"
STSQL = STSQL & " ("           
STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER_ITEM_NO,"
STSQL = STSQL & "INV_TYPE,"
STSQL = STSQL & "MTI_PART_NO,"
STSQL = STSQL & "DATE_ORDERED,"
STSQL = STSQL & "DATE_REQUIRED,"
STSQL = STSQL & "QUANTITY,"
STSQL = STSQL & "EMPLOYEE_ID,"
STSQL = STSQL & "MACHINE_ID,"
STSQL = STSQL & "COMMENTS,"
STSQL = STSQL & "JOB_NO,"
STSQL = STSQL & "PROCESS_PLAN_ID,"
'STSQL = STSQL & "ACCOUNT_NO"
STSQL = STSQL & "DESTINATION,"
STSQL = STSQL & "COMPLETED,"
STSQL = STSQL & "REQUEST_NO"
STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("  

STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Item) & "'," 'ORDER_ITEM_NO
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(InvType) & "'," 'INV_TYPE
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Mtipartno) & "'," 'MTI_PART_NO

STSQL = STSQL & "to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')," 'DATE_ORDERED
STSQL = STSQL & "to_date('" & Format(dateneed.Value, "dd-MMMM-yyyy") & "','DD-MON-YYYY')," 'DATE_REQUIRED

STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Quantity) & "'," 'QUANTITY
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(cboEmployee.SelectedValue) & "'," 'EMPLOYEE_ID
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(MachID) & "'," 'MACHINE_ID
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(TextBox2.Text) & "'," 'COMMENTS
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(Jobno) & "'," 'JOB_NO
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ProcPlanID) & "'," 'PROCESS_PLAN_ID
'STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(AcctNo) & "'," 'ACCOUNT_NO
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ComboBox2.SelectedText) & "'," 'DESTINATION
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & 0 & "'," 'COMPLETED
STSQL = STSQL & "'" & UCase(ReqNo) & "'" 'REQUEST_NO
```

Comment: I get the error that I cannot insert `NULL into ORDER_ID` so I am supposed to supply it.  I am inserting the next available order_id its not used.

Comment: are you using MS ACCESS?

Comment: No this is oracle.

Comment: first create CREATE SEQUENCE seq_order_id
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 100; now put seq_order_id as value in place of order_id

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you may use sequences to get an incrementing id.

```sql
INSERT INTO someTable ( yourSequence.NEXTVAL, ... )
```

Read the details here:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was given the wrong database to work from.  I was viewing 2 different sources.  So, everyone was right.  Thanks for everyone's help, it did lead into me poking around in other places to discover this.

Comment: Good to know you fixed the problem but you should also read up on how to build prepared statements using parameters and such.  Your way of creating SQL is prone to malicious attacks, data problems and performance issues.